# $15$ students collected $100$ flowers. Prove that at least two of them have collected the same number of flowers.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Question above. I'm really not sure how to proceed.

$15$ students collected $100$ flowers. Prove that at least two of them have collected the same number of flowers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say each one of them collected different number of flowers. In that case total number of flowers must be at least

$$0+1+2+3+...+14=105$$

And now $105>100$

It shows at least two of them collected same number of flowers.

Or

if everyone is collected at least one flower then

$$1+2+3+...+15=120$$

And now $120>100$

Comment: "In that case total number of flowers must be" should read "In that case total number of flowers must be at least"